# RED5 server and flash question

Tags: flash, red5

I am planning to create a video conferencing application finally in flash using RED5. But i don't know flash. Is there any readymade free video conference program available that i can directly integrate in my website? If not, then can anybody point me to from where should i start? Because gaining microphone and webcam access programmatically seems very daunting to me. If any good tutorials or any readymade applications are available then please suggest. I will be very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [openmeetings](http://code.google.com/p/openmeetings/) in google code.

There is a directory with open source flash stuff, [osflash](http://osflash.org/red5/showcase)